# Keyboard and Mouse only work in Recovery Mode Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, usb, keyboard, mouse, intel-nuc

I just got an Intel NUC Kit NUC5PGYH.  It has 8GB of RAM and a 500GB HDD.

**The Problem**

For the last week I've been trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from a USB drive.  Each time I'm able to successfully install the OS. However, when I load the OS, once I get to the GUI my mouse and keyboard stop working.  There is power coming to the mouse at least (As I can see the red light from the bottom of the mouse).

The keyboard and mouse both work in the BIOS settings and startup of the computer, and work during the installation process.  Additionally, if i load ubuntu in recovery mode the keyboard and mouse work!!

**What I've Tried**

- I've tried using different USB ports and even a USB hub, both made no
  difference.
- I've tried loading older kernels (not in recovery), again the
  keyboard and mouse don't work.
- I've loaded  Ubuntu in recovery mode, and run sudo apt-get update &&
  sudo apt-get upgrade successfully.  I also updated my Intel Graphics
  Card Drivers. However, still when I reboot the system the keyboard
  and mouse don't work.
- I've made sure my BIOS has USB Legacy Support On, still with no
  change.
- I've edited my grub.conf file (based on other suggestions) to turn on
  iommu, GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft", still no change.
- I've run a boot repair, again with no change.

If anyone has any suggestions or advice I'd really appreciate it, I don't know what else to do!!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

At first I was just doing these whenever my mouse stop working:

```
sudo rmmod usbhid
sudo modprobe usbhid
```

Then I tried this, and it worked ever since!

```
sudo aptitude purge irqbalance
```